# Seaborn heatmap - border squares are clipped off

Tags: python, macos, seaborn, heatmap

I was making a Seaborn heatmap and all went well, except for the fact that the border squares (top, right, bottom, left) are trimmed off...

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Please see my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

df_train = pd.read_csv('SongFeaturesTEST.csv')

# print(df_train.columns)
# print(df_train.corr())
# print(df_train.describe().T)

corrmat = df_train.corr(method='spearman')
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
sns.heatmap(corrmat, ax = ax, cmap="RdBu", linewidths=0.1, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 5})
plt.xticks(rotation=45, fontsize='5')
plt.yticks(fontsize='5')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a known problem with the latest version of `matplotlib` refer to the question I flagged as duplicate to check your solution

Comment: Thanks a lot. Found it tough to google it correctly as I could not find a solution